# This Next JS authentication expression is not callable in a Typescript file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am making a sign in method for my Next js application and am using the recommended documentation provided by the GitHub repo.

However when i reach the auth folder step i get this error. For the sign in providers.

in [...nextauth].ts

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("/Users/farishtawazir/Desktop/template/next-auth")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

I don't understand why as i have followed the documentation and still get this error

Here is the files code

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Auth0Provider from 'next-auth/providers/auth0'
import FacebookProvider from 'next-auth/providers/facebook'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import TwitterProvider from 'next-auth/providers/twitter'
// import AppleProvider from "next-auth/providers/apple"
// import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email"

// For more information on each option (and a full list of options) go to
// https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options
export default NextAuth({
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth
  providers: [
    /* EmailProvider({
         server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
         from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
       }),
    // Temporarily removing the Apple provider from the demo site as the
    // callback URL for it needs updating due to  changing domains
      
    Providers.Apple({
      clientId: process.env.APPLE_ID,
      clientSecret: {
        appleId: process.env.APPLE_ID,
        teamId: process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID,
        privateKey: process.env.APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
        keyId: process.env.APPLE_KEY_ID,
      },
    }),
    */
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    TwitterProvider({
      clientId: process.env.TWITTER_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_SECRET,
    }),
    Auth0Provider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,
    }),
  ],
  theme: {
    colorScheme: 'light',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token }: unknown) {
      token.userRole = 'admin'
      return token
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to set `"esModuleInterop": true` to true in your tsconfig.json

or you can also try:

```
import * as next-auth from 'next-auth';
```

Edit:

`import NextAuth from 'next-auth';` imports from the file `next-auth.d.ts`

i think you should move the file to a types folder as stated in this documentation https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation

if you rename/remove the file the error is gone

Comment: Hi i tried both methods but they dont seem to be working here is my tsconfig file

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "~/*": ["./public/*"]
    },
    "incremental": true

Comment: },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "process.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "next-auth.d.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "moduleResolution": ["node_modules", ".next", "node"]
}

Comment: Hi i made a sepearte branch called auth from the main i had to chnage the ts file to js for me to be able to push it if you find a soultion please respond

Comment: https://github.com/kingyousaf/Nextjs_production_tailwind

Comment: @user18371666 i editet my answer ... the file next-auth.d.ts is interfering with your import

Comment: @user18371666 if the answer helped fix your problem, please accept it

Comment: Types located in `./types/next-auth.d.ts` work,  types located in `./next-auth.d.ts.` don't. Tried with both paths included in `tsconfig`, of course. Weird @_@

Comment: Im stuck here, spent all day on it. Can please someone help me figure out what's causing this. The index.d.ts file in the node_modules looks perfectly fine so it seems that there is some type of conflict on which file it is consulting but i cant wrap my head around it

Comment: @Beikeni Hey, I'm having the same issue here. Maybe something changed recently? Have you tried downgrading your next-auth version? i.e I was using version 4.22.2 and changed it to 4.21.0 and the error is gone.

Comment: @Jonatan_lavado i had been thinking about that. Now that i have confirmation that it worked for you I can't wait to try it! I'll post here later if it works for me too

Comment: Strangely enough i downgraded next auth and it worked, then i had some other wonky error and i reupgraded it to 4.22.1 and it worked even better

Answer (score 1):

make sure you don't use **canary** version:

change this:

`"@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "canary",`

to this:

`"@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",`

make sure you added session config to your `next-auth.d.ts`

it should be like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
import "next-auth/jwt";

declare module "next-auth" {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    user: {
      /** The user's postal address. */
      address: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}

// Read more at: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    /** The user's role. */
    userRole?: "admin";
  }
}
```